# Custom math environment

Tags: math-mode, environments, latex3, xparse, alignment

Recently I've seen [this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIKXJ.png) and I felt that I'd like to have something similar, but with math environment, so that if I write a single line of equation, it will put it at the centre, like `equation` does. And if I add line break `\\`, it should be left-aligned.

Here is how it should look like:
[image]

---

And if it is possible I would also really like to be able to use `&` in order to make columns that are centered i.e. `&` is only responsible for the columns, not the alignment.

[image]

Comment: For the centred sibgle-lined equation, you have the `equation` environment (numbered) or  `\[ ... \]` (unnumbered). For the the multilined equations, use the dedicated environments from `amsmath` (`gather`,`align`, `alignat`, `multline`, `flalign`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really a good markup, in my opinion. But the customer is always right. `;-)`

The environment has an optional argument (default 2em) to set the spacing between columns.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mymath}{O{2em}b}
 {
  % #1 = spacing between columns, #2 = body
  \tl_if_in:nnT { #2 } { & }
   {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__antshar_mymath_ampersand_bool
   }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq = 1 }
   {
    \__antshar_mymath_single:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \__antshar_mymath_multiple:n { #1 }
   }
 }
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\seq_new:N \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq
\bool_new:N \l__antshar_mymath_ampersand_bool
\int_new:N \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__antshar_mymath_single:nn
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l__antshar_mymath_ampersand_bool
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq { & } { #2 }
    \[
    \begin{array}
     {
      @{}
      >{\displaystyle}c
      *{\int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq - 1 }}
       {@{\hspace{#1}}>{\displaystyle}c}
      @{}
     }
    #2
    \end{array}
    \]
   }
   {
    \[ #2 \]
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__antshar_mymath_multiple:n
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l__antshar_mymath_ampersand_bool
   {
    % count the maximum number of columns
    \int_zero:N \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq
     {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq { & } { ##1 }
      \int_set:Nn \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int
       {
        \int_max:nn { \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int } { \seq_count:N \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq }
       }
     }
    \[
    \begin{array}
     {
      @{}
      >{\displaystyle}c
      *{\int_eval:n { \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int - 1 } }
       {@{\hspace{#1}}>{\displaystyle}c}
      @{}
     }
    \seq_use:Nn \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq { \\\noalign{\vspace{\jot}} }
    \end{array}
    \]
   }
   {
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq
     {
      & \exp_not:n { {##1} } &&
     }
    \begin{flalign*}
    \seq_use:Nn \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq { \\ }
    \end{flalign*}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}
a=b
\end{mymath}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}
a=b & c=d & e=ffffffff
\end{mymath}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}
a=b & c=d & e=ffffffff \\
1=1 & 120\ne1000 & u
\end{mymath}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}[4em]
a=b & c=d & e=ffffffff
\end{mymath}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}
abc+def\\
=x+y
\end{mymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The image has been produced adding `showframe`.

#### Addition

The `mymath*` environment puts everything to the left.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mymath}{O{2em}b}
 {
  \bool_set_false:N \l__antshar_mymath_left_bool
  \antshar_mymath_main:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mymath*}{O{2em}b}
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l__antshar_mymath_left_bool
  \antshar_mymath_main:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\seq_new:N \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq
\bool_new:N \l__antshar_mymath_ampersand_bool
\bool_new:N \l__antshar_mymath_left_bool
\int_new:N \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \antshar_mymath_main:nn
 {
  % #1 = spacing between columns, #2 = body
  \tl_if_in:nnT { #2 } { & }
   {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__antshar_mymath_ampersand_bool
   }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq = 1 }
   {
    \__antshar_mymath_single:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \__antshar_mymath_multiple:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__antshar_mymath_single:nn
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l__antshar_mymath_ampersand_bool
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq { & } { #2 }
    \[
    \bool_if:NT \l__antshar_mymath_left_bool { \hspace{0pt} }
    \begin{array}
     {
      @{}
      >{\displaystyle}c
      *{\int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq - 1 }}
       {@{\hspace{#1}}>{\displaystyle}c}
      @{}
     }
    #2
    \end{array}
    \bool_if:NT \l__antshar_mymath_left_bool { \hspace{1000pt minus 1fill} }
    \]
   }
   {
    \[
    \bool_if:NT \l__antshar_mymath_left_bool { \hspace{0pt} }
    #2
    \bool_if:NT \l__antshar_mymath_left_bool { \hspace{1000pt minus 1fill} }
    \]
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__antshar_mymath_multiple:n
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l__antshar_mymath_ampersand_bool
   {
    % count the maximum number of columns
    \int_zero:N \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq
     {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq { & } { ##1 }
      \int_set:Nn \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int
       {
        \int_max:nn { \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int } { \seq_count:N \l__antshar_mymath_row_seq }
       }
     }
    \[
    \bool_if:NT \l__antshar_mymath_left_bool { \hspace{0pt} }
    \begin{array}
     {
      @{}
      >{\displaystyle}c
      *{\int_eval:n { \l__antshar_mymath_cols_int - 1 } }
       {@{\hspace{#1}}>{\displaystyle}c}
      @{}
     }
    \seq_use:Nn \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq { \\\noalign{\vspace{\jot}} }
    \end{array}
    \bool_if:NT \l__antshar_mymath_left_bool { \hspace{1000pt minus 1fill} }
    \]
   }
   {
    \[
    \hspace{0pt}
    \begin{array}{@{}>{\displaystyle}l@{}}
    \seq_use:Nn \l__antshar_mymath_body_seq { \\\noalign{\vspace{\jot}} }
    \end{array}
    \hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
    \]
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}
a=b
\end{mymath}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}
a=b & c=d & e=ffffffff
\end{mymath}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}
a=b & c=d & e=ffffffff \\
1=1 & 120\ne1000 & u
\end{mymath}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}[4em]
a=b & c=d & e=ffffffff
\end{mymath}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath}
abc+def\\
=x+y
\end{mymath}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath*}
a=b
\end{mymath*}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath*}
a=b & c=d & e=ffffffff
\end{mymath*}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath*}
a=b & c=d & e=ffffffff \\
1=1 & 120\ne1000 & u
\end{mymath*}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath*}[4em]
a=b & c=d & e=ffffffff
\end{mymath*}
Some text in front of the display, just for separation
\begin{mymath*}
abc+def\\
=x+y
\end{mymath*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: You've done a great job and absolutely did answer my original question. I'm really grateful for that. Don't want to seem impudent, but I'd like to know whether it is possible to put an asterisk, like so `mymath*` and have everything left-aligned, both single line and tabular-like structures?

Comment: @antshar Not so difficult, if you know how to do it. ;-)

Comment: Brilliant! You helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just remembered that you left such an amazing answer a couple of years ago. Now I'm struggling with [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645194/213149). Can you explain you managed to achieve just the right spacing in array, like in other amsmath environments?

Comment: @antshar I'd go with `IEEEeqnarray` (but first trying to limit the number of objects in displays).

Comment: But you still managed to do that even without `IEEEeqnarray`. Seems like I found what solves the problem: `\\\noalign{\vspace{\jot}}`. But how does it work exactly?